# How do automorphisms of a group act on the set of irreducible representations?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a finite group and $Rep(G)$ denote the set of all the irreducuble representations of $G$ (up to isomorphism, of course, so it is a finite set).

The problem is to define an action of $Aut(G)$ on $Rep(G)$ (the field is not mentioned so I guess it doesn't depend on the filed) and prove that inner automorphisms act trivially.

It must be something very standard by I don't know how am I supposed to come up with it. I am sure I would be able  to do the second part if I knew   what the action is.

Comment: A representation is a group homomorphism $\rho : G \to End(V)$. So, for every automorphism $f : G \to G$ you can compose $\rho \circ f$, and get a new representation. Can you go on now?

Comment: Well, ${\rm Rep}(G)$ depends on the field, so of course the action does.

Comment: Is this true that this action cannot be transitive unless all the dimensions of the irreducible representations are the same? I think we cannot obtain a representation of dimension $n$ from one of dimension less than n.

Comment: It should be obvious automorphisms of $G$ preserve dimensions of representations! Precomposing a homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$ with an automorphism of $G$ does not change the dimension of $V$! Indeed, the trivial rep is a fixed point, so the only group for which the action is transitive is the trivial group.